# Python using selenium, value_of_css_property different in output and inspection

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to determine which text is bold and which isn't, but all of the properties return as normal and I was hoping if someone could explain to me why, as well as the best to fix it or get around it.

My python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
urls = (
"http://www.espn.co.uk/rugby/match?gameId=290767&league=180659",
"http://www.espn.co.uk/rugby/match?gameId=290768&league=180659")

driver = webdriver.Chrome("c:/temp/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
driver.set_window_size(681,768)

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    ft = driver.find_element_by_class_name("game-time")
    if (ft.text) == "FT":
        #Opens player stats window
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="global-nav-tertiary"]/div/ul/li[6]""").click()

        posts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="main-container"]/div/div/div[1]/article/div/div[1]/div/div/div/table/tbody[1]/tr/td""")
        for post in posts:
            print post.value_of_css_property('font-weight')

        driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="main-container"]/div/div/div[1]/article/header/div/button[2]/span[2]""").click()

        posts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="main-container"]/div/div/div[1]/article/div/div[1]/div/div/div/table/tbody[1]/tr/td""")
        for post in posts:
            print post.value_of_css_property('font-weight')

    else:
        #skipping all games that haven't played yet
        pass
#closing driver
driver.quit()
```

Output:
normal

Element in Inspection:

```
<span class="name" style="font-weight:bold;" data-reactid=".88mmgctyio.2.0.0.0.$sq.1.0.0.0.0.0.2.$2.0.0.0.$name.0">Jonathan Davies, C </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get `CSS` property of `td` elements while you should handle `span` (they are not the same element- each has its own `'font-weight'` property):

```
for post in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="name"]'):
    print post.value_of_css_property('font-weight')
```